# Using MutationObserver instead of DOMSubtreeModified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using DOMSubtreeModified and it worked as expected but have tried to change the code to use the MutationObserver way instead. My implementation is however not outputting to console but is also not giving me any errors?

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.querySelector(".my-button");


// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');

        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');

        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

The html is:

```
<input type="submit" value="PRESS ME" class="my-button" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: Could you please share a portion of your HTML code too? I see your JS snippet comes from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example and it looks correct

Comment: @GrafiCode, I have added the html to my question.

Comment: allright, it seems you set your script to watch mutations of type: childlist and attributes. It means you will receive observations only when appending / removing children to / from your element or when you manipulare element's attributes. This means clicking the button won't trigger the observer, while `.setAttribute()` will fire up your observer, check this fiddle (it adds an `alt` attribute to the button) for more info https://jsfiddle.net/s50e74nj/